# Application freezes after use of pandas and matplotlib modules

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I wrote a script in python 3.4 where I'm making use of the tkinter module to build the GUI and pandas/matplotlib to visualise some data. The visualisation is being produced in a new window through the use of a button in the main window. The problem is that when I close the window that contains the graph (produced by pandas/matplot) the main window widgets are completely unresponsive. Furthermore, when I try to close the main window (through the 'X' button) I get a `Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate`, which I don't get if I close the window without producing the graphs.

In simple words: the rest of the application behaves as it should if I never produce the graphs and becomes completely unresponsive if I do.

Below are the code segments of the caller of the plotting method in the main window and the method itself where the use of pandas and matplot is clearly shown.

Caller:

```
button_view_browsers = tk.Button(window, text="Display graph", command=lambda: self.threaded_browser_hist(doc))
button_view_browsers.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, columnspan=3)
```

Visualisation method:

```
def display_browser_hist(self, data):
    ser = Series(data.viewer_browser())
    ser.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()

def threaded_browser_hist(self, doc):
    Thread(target=self.display_browser_hist(doc)).start()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Just to be sure I'm also including the modules I'm using and how I'm importing them:

```
from pandas import Series
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import W, E, N, S
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example which shows this?  Generally mixing embedding with `pyplot` does not work well.  Are you sure you are using the tkagg backend?  See the tk examples at http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually was not using tkagg. I made sure to add a `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` statement. If you can form that comment into an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Please answer your own question explaining how my cryptic comment translates to something that solved your problem ;)